# Scale element based on x position

Tags: javascript, math, scale

Math isn't my strongest area, I'm a little stuck on how to solve this.

Take this code, for example:

```
let node = document.querySelector('div');
let d;

function update({clientX}) {
  if(!d) return; // Dragging?

  let w = innerWidth; // Window width
  let s = ...; // Scale value?

  node.style.transform = `translateX(${v}) scale(${s})`;
};

node.onmousedown = () => d = true;
node.onmouseup = () => d = false;
node.onmousemove = update;
```

Imagine I'm dragging the div from left to right in the browser window, how can I make it so when it's at the centre of the screen it's at a `1.0` scale, and when it reaches the outer edges it gets increasingly smaller to `0.0`?

Comment: Cross-multiply and divide, for scaling.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Is it possible you could give an example as an answer? I have no idea how to implement that logic.

Comment: Usually if something has scale `0.0` it doesn't show (because `actual_length = scale*default_length`) and so the length would be zero in that case. Is this the behaviour you're thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to just scale by percent?

```
function scaleByPercent(element, percent){
  var p = percent/100, e = element.getBoundingClientRect(), w = e.width, h = e.height;
  e.style.width = w*p+w; e.style.height = h*p+h;
}
scaleByPercent(document.getElementById('yourDivId'), 25);
```

Of course, you would have to change the percent as you do your drag.